# Mysql Update statement with variable in python

Tags: python, mysql

So my problem is that I have written a python code to ask the name and update name to a specific column of a table of mysql. I have made sure that connection is established and there is no problem with other syntax . But it shows error saying no attribute encode of tuple object . My code is as  below :

```
z = input("enter book id:") 
u = input("enter name:") 
an = "UPDATE table1 SET namecolumn=%s WHERE id = %s" 
c=(u,(z,))
cursor.execute(an,c) 
mydb.commit()
```

In this above code I can't update name as it says error: tuple object has no attribute encode 
So please help and tell what is wrong in my code.

Comment: The problem is the syntax, you should pass a tuple to the cursor.execute. Currently you are passing a tuple where the second element is another tuple. The correct syntax should be: `c=(u,z)`

Comment: I have tried your method but it doesn't work . Actually the column in which z is putting value is defined as int and the column in which u is putting value is defined as varchar . The z part is working alone but with u part it shows error.